# How to do integration in mfile just like in Simulink in matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am not sure why this code is not working:

```
if true
  %% PID Test file
% Start the script
clear
clc
kp = 180;
kI = 3200;
kD = 1;
start_time = 0;
step_time = 1;
end_time = 2;
Ts = 0.1;% Sample Time
step_value = 1;
initial_value = 0;
Fn = 50;
  W = 2*pi*Fn;
  Phase = 0;
  Amp = 1;
steps = 1;
if steps
[t,y] = step_fun(start_time,step_time,end_time,Ts,step_value,initial_value);
sim('PID_Test_sim.mdl')
else
  t = start_time:Ts:end_time;
  y = sin(W*t);
  sim('PID_Test_sim.mdl')
end
x_min = start_time;
x_max = end_time;
y_min = initial_value - 1;
y_max = step_value + 1;
figure();
subplot(2,1,1);
stairs(t,y);grid on;hold on; stairs(ScopeData.time,ScopeData.signals(1,2).values,'--r');hold off;%y([y_min y_max]);xlim([x_min x_max]);
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,y);grid on;hold on; plot(ScopeData.time,ScopeData.signals(1,2).values,'--r');hold off;%y([y_min y_max]);xlim([x_min x_max]);
Input = y;
time = t;
dt = diff(time);
D = [0,diff(Input.*kD) ./ dt]';
I = [cumtrapz(time,(Input.*kI))]';
%I = [0;(I(1:end-1)+I(2))];
I_test = I;
I_test(I_test>0) = (I(find(I>0,1,'first'))) + I(I>0);
I_test = [0,I_test(1:end-1)];
P = [Input*kp]';
Compare = ScopeData1;
figure();
subplot(3,1,1);
stairs(time,P);grid on;hold on; stairs(Compare.time,Compare.signals(1,1).values,'--r');hold off
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(time,I);grid on;hold on; plot(Compare.time,Compare.signals(1,2).values,'--r');hold off
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(time,D);grid on;hold on; plot(Compare.time,Compare.signals(1,3).values,'--r');hold off
Test = [I ScopeData1.signals(1,2).values time'];
[time,Output] = PID_fun(kp,kI,kD,Input,time,ScopeData1);
figure();
subplot(2,1,1);
stairs(t,y);grid on;hold on; stairs(ScopeData.time,ScopeData.signals(1,2).values,'--r');hold off;
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(time,Output);grid on;hold on; plot(ScopeData.time,ScopeData.signals(1,1).values,'--r');hold off;
Test = [I ScopeData1.signals(1,2).values I_test P ScopeData1.signals(1,1).values D ScopeData1.signals(1,3).values time' Output ScopeData.signals(1,1).values];
```

It is a very simple code that generate a step signal (in step_fun) and sfterword run the simulation mdl which is a PID controller with step function as input. and then i am running my PID function which is explained later by variables (P,I,D) and in the integration i am becomming different results between simulation and mfile? can you help me with this? ther results are:

```
     % code
% My integration results of the input signal when kI = 3200;
mfile    simulation
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
160 0
480 320
800 640
1120    960
1440    1280
1760    1600
2080  1920
2400  2240
2720  2560
3040  2880
3360  3200
```

here is some figures with the results:
[image: Comparing the input and outputs of the mfile and simulink PID]
[image: Comparing the outputs of the PID from simulink and mfile]

Best Regards and thx in advance

Comment: Without being able to run even the non-Simulink part of your code makes providing useful help difficult. The plots aren't helpful, but from the printed numbers it looks like the two simulation may be doing the same thing with just an offset in time. You say that the Simulink uses a fixed time step but then you use `diff` to calculate a vector `dt`. The values in the vector should be close, but numerical error may be present. Try using an actual fixed time step. And what determines the onset time of the step? Maybe a `>` needs to be a `>=` or some such.

Comment: first of all thx for the replay. you are unable to run the non-Simulink code coz u dont have "step_fun". for the figures u will not be able to run them as they are a compare between the simulation results and the mfile results. so in ur case if u just wana run my code i advice that: 1- set the variable (steps = 1) to Zero and then u will generate a sin wave which still cant be compared to simulation as u dont have the simulation modle which is only a PID block with an input of a sine wave or step wave which have the same properties as generated in the mfile. so u can do it actually urself!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally i did answer my own question :)

the simulation takes the integration on the point beofer the current one t(i-1) yet the cumtrapz takes the integration for the current point t(i) and that is the differents.

as a results i have changes my cumtrapz to cumtrapzt where i calculated the diff(t) till t(i-1) of the given data set (t(end-1))

thx for the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell without seeing the Simulink model, but I suspect that in Simulink you are using a variable-step solver, which is able to take much smaller time steps than in your MATLAB file, giving you more accurate results.

If you have the Control System Toolbox, I would suggest that you use the [`pid`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/pid.html) command to create the PID in MATLAB and then the [`step`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/step.html) or [`lsim`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/lsim.html) command to compute the step response, rather than your manual attempt. My guess is that the results will be much closer.

Comment: Thx for your replay. I am using in simulink the same step time (Ts) and in mfile and i am also doing the simuliation for a fixed step solver with Ts as step time. the simulink mdl i am using is just an implementation of the mfile in simulink (you can see that the results have the same number of index) so i am still not sure why i am getting a different results. i have the tool yet i want to use my own mfile as my data are very big and i don't want to lose time on such methods (i am saving about 40 min of simulation when doing it with my own mfile)

Comment: It's probably because you are using a fixed-step solver that it's taking so long. Use a variable-step solver and it'll be a lot quicker. Simulink is the right tool for simulating complex systems in the time domain. Have you tried using `pid` and `step`/`lsim` for your MATLAB code?

Comment: yes and no. I know i can use the pid function directly, yet i don't want to. I am doing some flicker evaluation of a three  phase measured voltages and currents signals. (10min data with Fs >= 20 kHz) as part of this evaluation i need to get the PLL of those signals in order to generate a grid voltage signal without any flicker values (Pst = 0, Plt = 0). i have already identify my Zerocrossing and calculated the frequency after that the W = 2*pi*f and finally i need to get the Wt which is the intgration of W. so i need the cumtrapz to work correctly so i have a correct Wt of my measured signal